# Actionscript3/Starling setup so image follows touch (while dragging) mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, flash-builder, starling-framework

I am trying to make an image appear when I touch the screen. While my finger is on the screen, I want the image to follow my finger. When I release my finger, I want the image to stop moving and stay in the position where it was when I released my finger. This is my first time working with touch screens, so I realize some of my code may be way off. Here is the code from Game.as (which gets initialized in a file called Startup.as, which is the main file):

Game.as

```
package
{

import com.demonsters.debugger.MonsterDebugger;

import Classes.Avatar;
import Classes.AvatarEnemy;

import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.EnterFrameEvent;
import starling.events.Touch;
import starling.events.TouchEvent;
import starling.events.TouchPhase;

    public class Game extends Sprite
    {   
        public var enemy:AvatarEnemy;
        public var avatar:Avatar;

        private var paused2:Boolean = false;

        private var counter:int = 0;

        [Embed(source='Classes/Avatarpic.png')]
        private static var Avatarpic:Class;

        public function Game() 
        {   
            avatar.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);

            addEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, doCounter);

            enemy = new AvatarEnemy();
            addChild(enemy);

            avatar = new Avatar();
        }

        private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void
        {
            addChild(avatar);

            if (paused2) {
                return;
            }

            var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(avatar, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
            var touch2:Touch = e.getTouch(avatar, TouchPhase.HOVER);
            var touch3:Touch = e.getTouch(avatar, TouchPhase.ENDED);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN && !paused2) {
                avatar.addEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, withImage);
            }
            if (touch2.phase == TouchPhase.HOVER) {
                stage.color = 0xff0000;
                removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, doCounter);
                avatar.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
                paused2 = true;
            }
            if (touch3.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED) {
                avatar.removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, withImage);
            }

            function withImage():void {
                avatar.x = touch.globalX;
                avatar.y = touch.globalY;
            }
        }

        public function getScore():int {
            return counter;
        }

        public function getIsOver():Boolean {
            return paused2;
        }

        private function doCounter():void
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

I start with adding a listener for the `TouchEvent` - it calls the method `onTouch`, which is my attempt at making the app do what I described above. There is a counter, which ends up being the "score" for the game (how many frames have passed) - and the `paused2` variable handles when the game is over. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Right now, when I test on my iPhone, all I see is a white screen...when I touch the screen the avatar doesn't get added with `addChild(avatar)`. Also, the `enemy` sprite doesn't show up either, even though I used `addChild(enemy)` to add it. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

THIS CODE REPLACED THE CODE ABOVE:

It seems as if the `TouchEvent` listener isn't firing at all (I used `trace` to deduce this) - I changed some things around in terms of what is handled where, so I need to paste more code:

Game.as

```
package
{

import com.demonsters.debugger.MonsterDebugger;

import Classes.Avatar;
import Classes.AvatarEnemy;

import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.EnterFrameEvent;
import starling.events.Touch;
import starling.events.TouchEvent;
import starling.events.TouchPhase;
import starling.events.Event;

    public class Game extends Sprite
    {   
        public var enemy:AvatarEnemy;
        public var avatar:Avatar;

        private var paused2:Boolean = false;

        [Embed(source='Classes/Avatarpic.png')]
        private static var Avatarpic:Class;

        public function Game() 
        {               
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch); //On touch of this image, do onTouch
        }

        private function onAdded():void {
            enemy = new AvatarEnemy();
            enemy.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            enemy.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            addChild(enemy);

            avatar = new Avatar();
            avatar.x = stage.stageWidth/3;
            avatar.y = stage.stageHeight/3;
            avatar.touchable = true;
            avatar.name = "avatar";
            addChild(avatar);
            trace(getChildAt(0));
        }

        private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void
        {
            trace("you touched it");

            if (paused2) {
                return;
            }

            var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(avatar, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
            var touch2:Touch = e.getTouch(avatar, TouchPhase.HOVER);
            var touch3:Touch = e.getTouch(avatar, TouchPhase.ENDED);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN && !paused2) {
                /*stage.color = 0xff0000;
                paused2 = true;*/
                avatar.addEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, withImage);
            }
            if (touch2.phase == TouchPhase.HOVER) {
                stage.color = 0xff0000;
                //removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, withImage);
                removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
                paused2 = true;
            }
            if (touch3.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED) {
                avatar.removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, withImage);
            }
            /*if (touch3.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED && paused2) {
            removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, withImage);
            image2.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);

            }*/

            function withImage():void {
                avatar.x = touch.globalX;
                avatar.y = touch.globalY;
            }
        }

        public function getIsOver():Boolean {
            return paused2;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.as

```
package 
{

    import com.demonsters.debugger.MonsterDebugger;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.system.Security;

    import Classes.Avatar;

    import io.socket.flash.ISocketIOTransport;
    import io.socket.flash.ISocketIOTransportFactory;
    import io.socket.flash.SocketIOErrorEvent;
    import io.socket.flash.SocketIOEvent;
    import io.socket.flash.SocketIOTransportFactory;
    import io.socket.flash.XhrPollingTransport;

    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.events.EnterFrameEvent;
    import starling.events.Touch;
    import starling.events.TouchEvent;
    import starling.events.TouchPhase;


    [SWF(width="640", height="960", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
    public class Startup extends Sprite
    {       
        private var mStarling:Starling;

        //Create referencable cursor image.
        //[Embed(source="Classes/Avatarpic.png")]
        //public const Cursor:Class;

        /*public var cursor;
        private var cursorBitmapData:BitmapData;
        private var cursorData:MouseCursorData;
        private var cursorVector:Vector.<BitmapData>;*/

        private var _socketIOTransportFactory:ISocketIOTransportFactory = new SocketIOTransportFactory();
        private var _ioSocket:ISocketIOTransport;
        //private var enemyaccess:AvatarEnemy;
        private var Game2:Game;

        private var counter:int = 0;

        public function Startup()
        {
            Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:10843");

            createSocket();
            MonsterDebugger.initialize(this);

            // Create a Starling instance that will run the "Game" class
            mStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);
            mStarling.start();

            //createCustomCursor(); //Create cursor

            // These settings are recommended to avoid problems with touch handling
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            mStarling.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED, onAdded);
        }

        private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void {
            var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(Game2, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN) {
                trace("touched");
            }
        }

        private function checkForScore(Event):void {
            if(Game2.getIsOver()) {
                MonsterDebugger.trace(this, "Made it to score check:" + " " + counter);
                send(int(counter));
                Game2.removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, checkForScore);
                Game2.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
            }
            counter++;
        }

        private function onAdded():void {
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, "Root created");
            //enemyaccess = (Starling.current.root as Game).enemy;
            Game2 = (Starling.current.root as Game);
            Game2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
            Game2.addEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, checkForScore);
        }

        /*private function createCustomCursor():void
        {   
            cursor = new Cursor();
            cursorBitmapData = new BitmapData(32, 32, true, 0x000000); //Create empty bitmapdata object.
            cursorBitmapData.draw(cursor); //draw cursor on canvas of bitmapdata object.

            cursorVector = new Vector.<BitmapData>();
            cursorVector[0] = cursorBitmapData; //store image in vector.

            cursorData = new MouseCursorData();
            cursorData.hotSpot = new Point(0, 0);
            cursorData.data = cursorVector;

            //Register cursors
            Mouse.registerCursor("cursor", cursorData);
            Mouse.cursor = "cursor";

        }*/

        private function createSocket():void {
            _ioSocket = _socketIOTransportFactory.createSocketIOTransport(XhrPollingTransport.TRANSPORT_TYPE, "192.168.1.7:8000/socket.io", this);
            _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOEvent.CONNECT, onSocketConnected);
            _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOEvent.DISCONNECT, onSocketDisconnected);
            _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOEvent.MESSAGE, onSocketMessage);
            _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOErrorEvent.CONNECTION_FAULT, onSocketConnectionFault);
            _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOErrorEvent.SECURITY_FAULT, onSocketSecurityFault);
            _ioSocket.connect();
        }

        private function onSocketConnectionFault(event:SocketIOErrorEvent):void
        {
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, event.type + ":" + event.text);
        }
        private function onSocketSecurityFault(event:SocketIOErrorEvent):void
        {
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, event.type + ":" + event.text);
        }
        private function onDisconnectClick():void
        {
            _ioSocket.disconnect();
        }
        private function onSocketMessage(event:SocketIOEvent):void
        {
            if (event.message is String)
            {
                MonsterDebugger.trace(this, String(event.message));
            }
            else
            {
                MonsterDebugger.trace(this, JSON.stringify(event.message));
            }
        }
        public function send(data:Object):void
        {
            _ioSocket.send(data);
        }
        private function onSocketConnected(event:SocketIOEvent):void
        {
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, "Connected" + event.target);
        }
        private function onSocketDisconnected(event:SocketIOEvent):void
        {
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, "Disconnected" + event.target);
        }
    }
}
```

Avatar.as and AvatarEnemy.as simply add the image using `addChild(image)`;

Lines to focus on right now are:

From Startup.as:

```
Game2 = (Starling.current.root as Game);
Game2.removeEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, checkForScore);
Game2.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
```

and the `onTouch` method:

```
private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void {
    var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(Game2, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN) {
        trace("touched");
    }
}
```

The trace from within the onTouch method doesn't get logged in the console when I touch the screen.

Comment: @Gary Perry - watup dawg - any help?

Comment: Well there isn't just a 'right way' to do it. Start making some efforts - what's the problem, why isn't working? Add the child at the beginning and just move it on touch. We cannot help you just like that :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov - lol - thanks i guess - i did try that BEFORE posting on stack and it didnt work - i've since changed some things so i'll try it again and see if it works - I am making effort lol!

Comment: @AndreyPopov take a look - see if you can get it - touch functionality still isnt working.

Comment: Where are you up to with this atm? You get initial avatar and enemy objects on stage but not touch events firing? With your initial touch, are you touching the avatar or just anywhere on the screen?

Comment: @InkeyDollarDan I figured it out, I'm working on something else right now (part of the same project). I'm going to post the answer, I have just been busy.

Comment: cool, glad you got it sorted